# User unable to login if user's roles are huge in asp.net core #

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-roles

My current web application with asp.net core 2 is behaving somehow of which I don't understand. I created users  with identity system which is working fine and I also created Roles with `RoleManager<IdentityRole>` that are up to 300 roles which is also working fine.

Now what I observed from login page is, if I assign Roles to user which are not much like less than 100 for instance, user will login successfully using SignInManager. But if I assign more than 100 Roles or all Roles to user, the login wouldn't be successful and if I check the cookies from the browser, I found out that it's multiply up to 5 times of the normal cookies value.

What could be the issue, is it that asp.net core 2 have Roles restriction because these was working fine in asp.net mvc  5 before I migrate to asp.net core 2.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer Noted Thanks.